# Does redux thunk wait until all earlier dispatched actions modified the store?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

```
handleDeleteClick = propertyName => () => {
  this.props.clearFilterOption(propertyName, this.props.filtersPropertyName);
  this.props.onFilterClear();
};
```

`handleDeleteClick` function is a button handler. My first redux action `clearFilterOption` modifies the store. The second action `onFilterClear` is the asynchronous action that maps filter params from redux-thunk's `getState` and calls api. My question is - does redux thunk wait for earlier dispatched action that modifies the store? In other words - do I have a certainty that the second action will fire with the most recent store version?

For now it works as expected. The second action fires with cleared filter option. But I don't know if it's because I'm using redux-thunk, or because `clearFilterOption` for now, is a low cost function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Thunk middleware doesn't 'wait' as such, all it does is looks at the action that's been dispatched, and if it's a function it calls it.

The order that your store is modified is governed by your actions and whether they're asynchronous or not.

In your case, if your first action `clearFilterOption` is synchronous then it will always update the store before the second action is dispatched. If it isn't synchronous then it depends on the timings of whatever is happening within your Thunks.

If you always need one thing to occur before the other you should chain your actions (as Thunks) rather than dispatching them sequentially in your `handleDeleteClick`.

Comment: Thanks Will! So my code is 100% correct, but I should keep in mind that the first action will not became asynchronous. Right?

Comment: Yes, as long as first action isn't async it's safe.